# Spring batch FlatFileItemWriter to add comma on end of line

Tags: spring, spring-batch

We have request to format row like this:

```
886,89,5052299385882,1,
```

Problem is last character of row which should be comma, it is export job for integration so this request is dictated from another side. Is there easy way to achieve this with FlatFileItemWriter?

Currently we modeled our java representation of row to have additional string which is always empty, and told field extractor to extract blank filed as last value for row creation but I am searching for a way to append something on each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FlatFileItemWriter` has a `lineAggregator` property.
Write your own implementation of [LineAggregator interface](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/transform/LineAggregator.html) (a delegation should be enough) and add a comma to returned string.

Comment: Thanks for answer, this is indeed much nicer approach and removes field in object which does not add any value